# How to replace output textbox in html5?

Tags: javascript, html

Hopefully someone can help me.

when im input: "my name is jack".

Ouputput can display change: "my name is clara".

jack change with clara.

but when im input: "my name is toni"

Ouputput still display: "my name is toni"

that text "toni" can't change with "ana"

what's wrong with my code?, 
this my code

```html
<html>
<body>

Enter Text: <input type="text" id="myText">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Replace</button>

<p id="check"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
 var y = x.replace("toni", "ana");
 document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = y;
 var z = x.replace("jack", "clara");
 document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = z;
 }
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

sorry for my bad english

Thankyou...

Comment: You spelled `suzi` wrong in your code `suzi != ana`

Comment: The problem is that you are performing two replaces in a row and the last one overwrite the result of the first. What do you want to do if the string contains both *toni* and *jack*? Should only one of them be replaced (with what priority order?) or both?

Comment: thanks for reply.. how  can to solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own function, to define original and new names into arrays and match them:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Enter Text: <input type="text" id="myText">
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Replace</button>
        <p id="check"></p>

        <script>
            String.prototype.replaceArr = function(find, replace) {
                var replaceString = this;
                var regex;
                for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
                    regex = new RegExp(find[i], "g");
                    replaceString = replaceString.replace(regex, replace[i]);
                }
                return replaceString;
            }

            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
                var oldNames = ['toni', 'jack'];
                var newNames = ['ana', 'clara'];
                document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = x.replaceArr(oldNames, newNames);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this line by line:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
```

X now contains the original text value, with no replacements.

```
var y = x.replace("toni", "ana");
```

Y contains the original text value with "toni" replaced by "ana".

```
document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = y;
```

You place Y inside the document.

```
var z = x.replace("jack", "clara");
```

That was the bug. Z contains the *original text value* with "jack" replaced by "clara". Note that this ignores the replacement you did in Y.

```
document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = z;
```

Now you place Z inside the document (overwriting the change you made earlier).

A simple way to resolve your issue without substantially rewriting your code would be to drop all the unnecessary intermediate variables, and do all the replacements on the same string before placing it back in the DOM:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
x = x.replace("toni", "ana");
x = x.replace("jack", "clara");
document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = x;
```

Comment: thanks for replaying.. im a student and beginer with javascript.

thankyou so much for explaining my wrong code. :)